# AG Grid: you can only use an enterprise datasource when gridOptions.rowModelType is 'serverSide'

Tags: ag-grid

We have a enterprise license for ag-grid. I'm trying to bind the server side datasource to ag-grid, but it's not calling the server datasource method and giving this warning `"AG Grid: you can only use an enterprise datasource when gridOptions.rowModelType is 'serverSide'"`  in console.

I've given correct key, imported ag-grid-enterprise as well in the component module.

Component template:

```
     <ag-grid-angular [columnDefs]="columns" [rowData]="rowData" [pagination]="true"
       [paginationPageSize]="itemsPerPage" [suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns]="true"
       [enableCellTextSelection]="true" [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef" [suppressExcelExport]="false"
       [suppressContextMenu]="false" [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents" [popupParent]="popupParent"
       class="ag-theme-balham" style="width: 100%; height: 550px" (gridSizeChanged)="onGridSizeChanged($event)"
       (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" (firstDataRendered)="headerHeightSetter($event)"
       (columnResized)="headerHeightSetter($event)" [sideBar]="sideBar" [rowModelType]="rowModelType"
       [cacheBlockSize]="cacheBlockSize" [serverSideStoreType]="serverSideStoreType">
     </ag-grid-angular>
```

Component.ts:

```
  private gridApi;
  private gridColumnApi;
  public rowData: [];
  itemsPerPage: number = 100;
  rowModelType: 'serverSide';
  serverSideStoreType: 'full';
  cacheBlockSize: 20;

...

  onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
    var datasource = this.createServerSideDatasource();
    params.api.setServerSideDatasource(datasource);
    this.gridApi.resetRowHeights();
  }

...

 createServerSideDatasource() {
    return {
      getRows: function (params) {
        console.log('[Datasource] - rows requested by grid: ', params.request);
        //TODO: offset and limit should be sent based on the pagination.. 
        let inputPayload = {
          offset: this.offset,
          limit: this.itemsPerPage
        }

        this.apiService.execute(ApiEndPoint.Products, inputPayload).subscribe((res: any) => {
          console.log(res);
          params.success({
            rowData: res.body[0].data,
            rowCount: res.body[0].data.length // response.lastRow,
          });
        }, err => {
          console.log(err);
          params.fail();
        });
      }
    };
  }
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. ClientModel still works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, its my bad.. typical mistake we do in Angular at times when we ignore to define the datatype but assigning the value alone.

In component.ts I made the blunder while assigning the values:

```
  private gridApi;
  private gridColumnApi;
  public rowData = []; // earlier it was like this -> public rowData: [];
  itemsPerPage: number = 100;
  rowModelType = 'serverSide'; // earlier it was like this -> rowModelType: 'serverSide';
  serverSideStoreType = 'full'; // earlier it was like this -> serverSideStoreType: 'full';
  cacheBlockSize = 20; // earlier it was like this -> cacheBlockSize: 20;
```

After correcting this, grid has fetched the data as expected!

Answer (score 0):

Don't set `rowData` property on the grid. Doing so implies client-side row model.

Comment: Removing it doesn't help. I'm using grid v26.2.0. I'm not sure if this version has any issues in binding to the serverSide datasource or expecting us to follow any specific interface type.